# Autocomplete on InputBox: Uncaught Type Error: undefine is not a function In jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

When I select any value it gives me error and when I focus any item it gives the same error again.

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var posting = $http({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/auto",
            data: request
        }) // request is the value of search input
        posting.success(function (data) {
            console.log('hello43434');
            // Map response values to fiedl label and value
            response($.map(data, function (el) {
                return {
                    label: el.name,
                    value: el._id
                };
            }));
        })
        posting.error(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    },
```

---

That is the sequence of my all file

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="schscript/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="schscript/schAngularController.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Are you sure your syntax is correct? You are missing `;` before `success` and `error` callbacks.

Comment: @SandeepNayak That is not syntax error. `Automatic Semicolon Insertion` comes into play.

Comment: @shubham Have you injected `$http` service into controller. Please create jsfiddle

Comment: Autocomplete is working properly But my console give error